# Memory Management issues with NSPointerArray and char *

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a `char *` and I process it with `strtok` and get a copy of every line I get with `strdup`.
This `char *` is used as a param for a function which stores the pointers in a `NSMutableArray` which holds instances of the `NSPointerArray`.
The problem is I get when I call release on `NSMutableDictionary` in dealloc the message 
message send to deallocated instance`. 
So I think something is terrible wrong here...
Here some code:

```
proceedDataBlock = ^(const char *data){

            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

            int counter = 0;
            char *temp = strdup(data);
            char *cline = strtok(temp, "\n");
            Table *dataList = [[Table alloc] initWithType:m.Type groups:groupings];
            while(cline)
            {
                 // do something
                 [myObject addString:strdup(cline)];
                 cline = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            }
            free(temp);
 [callbackObj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(recieveDataModelsFinished:)
```

withObject:[dataList autorelease] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

The `myObject:addString` looks like:

```
-(void)addString:(char *)line
{
// models is an NSMutableArray
    char cGroup = line[32];
    NSString *group = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", cGroup];
    NSPointerArray *dataArray = [self.models objectForKey:group];
        [dataArray addPointer:line];
}
```

Now when I release my Object and the dealloc get called:

```
-(void)dealloc
{    
    [_models release];
    [_type release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I get for every entry in my `_models` dictionary the message 
`message send to deallocated instance`.

EDIT:
Here I create the models dictionary and it contents:

```
    self.models = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:100];

if (mappings.count > 0)
{
    self.groupings = [mappings retain];

    for (GroupingInfo *group in self.groupings)
    {
        NSPointerArray *dataArray = [[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsCStringPersonality];
        [self.models setValue:dataArray forKey:group.key];
        [dataArray release];
    }
}
else
{
    NSPointerArray *dataArray = [[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsCStringPersonality];
    [self.models setValue:dataArray forKey:ALLITEMS_GROUP_KEY];
    [dataArray release];
}
```

}

EDIT2:
I only get this message when I step through my dealloc in the debugger, then I saw this messages (but no crash happened) if I don`t step through nothing happened.

Comment: How is `models` populated? This just appears to show how the pointer arrays inside models are populated, which does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: oh I forget about that, I edit it

Comment: If, as your comments state, "models" is an NSMutableArray, how can you execute objectForKey on it?

Comment: Sorry I mean NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard this in the Apple Forums: "If you get that message only when stepping through the code in the debugger then this is a know problem with the debugger. The debugger messages objects when you step through the code to get their description. If an object is dealloced but is still in scope the debugger will still message the dealloced object, resulting in the console output about messaging a deallocated instance." So I hope its a problem with the debugger.